# how to grep lines with patterns in a seperate file using sed or awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

I've a big data file (`data.txt`) and a pattern file (`patt.dat`) and the data is like below

**data.txt**

```
[bottle]:[some description 1]    
[pen]:[some description 2]    
[mobile]:[some description 3]       
[pen_pencil]:[some description 4]  
[mouse]:[some description 5]
```

**patt.dat**

```
pen    
mobile
```

i give like this

```
grep -F -f patt.dat data.txt
```

then i get the below

```
[pen]:[some description 2]    
[mobile]:[some description 3]    
[pen_pencil]:[some description 4]
```

but I want only want,

```
[pen]:[some description 2]    
[mobile]:[some description 3]
```

Please help with any solution.
I don't want to hard code anything because there'll be a lot of such patterns and hard-coding all won't look good.

If the same can be achieved in any other way possibly, please suggest that one too.

Comment: use word boundary `\b`

Comment: i imagine that `[bad]:[pen]` is to reject also and only full word in first `[]` is needed (adapt your question for clarity about what you want exactly)

Answer (score 4):

Use -w for word match as well like:

```
grep -wf patt.dat data.txt 
Output:
[pen]:[some description 2]
[mobile]:[some description 3]
```

Comment: @BhanuPrakash: please accept this answer :) I did not find it the first time.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/.*/^\[&]/' patt.dat > /tmp/patt_grep.dat
egrep -F -f /tmp/patt_grep.dat data.txt
```

need to change a bit the patt.dat content to allow another efficient tool to work. I use egrep to allow the `^` but a (f)grep could be used changing the to format `[word]:[` instead

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it with  `awk`

```
awk -F"[][]" 'FNR==NR {a[$1];next} $2 in a' patt.dat data.txt
[pen]:[some description 2]
[mobile]:[some description 3]
```

If you like to test on more parameters, `awk` may be the simplest solution.
It stores the pattern in array `a`, then test if field `2` is found in array `a`,  if found, print the line.